# Why does Loki stagger when he's leaving the Tessaract research facility with Barton?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012, loki

He staggers, and the security guard helps him stay on his feet. What makes Loki stagger?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think the other post answers this question since Loki acts weak in the back of the truck. I questioned that interpretation when I considered it before, since he's so effective between the time he appears and leaves the facility. The only argument for leaving this question up would be that I wasn't able to find the other question and its answer in my pre-posting googling.